# How to get data from XML with ID PHP

Tags: php, xml

I get XML:

```
$xml= simplexml_load_file('');
```

I have XML:

```
<ValCurs Date="22.12.2018" name="Foreign Currency Market">
 <Valute ID="R01011">
  <NumCode>036</NumCode>
  <CharCode>AUD</CharCode>
  <Nominal>1</Nominal>
  <Name>Dollar A</Name>
  <Value>10</Value>
 </Valute>
 <Valute ID="R01012">
  <NumCode>036</NumCode>
  <CharCode>AUD</CharCode>
  <Nominal>1</Nominal>
  <Name>Dollar B</Name>
  <Value>30</Value>
 </Valute>
 <Valute ID="R01013">
  <NumCode>036</NumCode>
  <CharCode>AUD</CharCode>
  <Nominal>1</Nominal>
  <Name>Dollar C</Name>
  <Value>20</Value>
 </Valute>
</ValCurs>
```

I need get Name and Value where Valute ID="R01013", how i can get it?
I try:

```
$xml->Valute_ID="R01013"->Name;
$xml->Valute_ID="R01013"->Value;
```

But it isn't work.

Comment: Where is your code? How do you get the `$xml` object?

Comment: Option without DOM is? And it isn't parsing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using SimpleXML and XPath makes this quite trivial.  First load the data (in this case my data is in a file called 'bok.xml' - but I assume you already have this part).

Then use XPath to look for a `Valute` element with the attribute `ID` (indicated by `@` to show it's an attribute) and the value you want to find.

As XPath returns a list of matches, and there is only one then use `[0]`, then you can use the `->Name` etc to get the values your after...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("bok.xml");
$valute = $xml->xpath('//Valute[@ID="R01013"]');
echo $valute[0]->Name;
```